# Java: Date manipulation

Tags: java, calendar, jtextfield, date-formatting

I'm trying to modify the date using SimpleDateFormat and Calendar object. Then writes modified date into my database. The problem is, my method won't compile. It says: Incompatible types String cannot be converted to Date. What did i miss?
This is my method

```
public Date expiredItem() {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar expiredDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    expiredDate.add(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(timeFld.getText()));
    //timeFld is JTextField.getText() casted into int

    // The confusing thing is, below Dialog works as i expected but not on my
    // method return.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Expiration Date: " +       
    dateFormat.format(expiredDate.getTime()));
    return  dateFormat.format(expiredDate.getTime()); //Erroneous code
}
```

Comment: I just found out my return statements are String but my method returns Date. But how do I fix this to let my method returns formattedDate?

Comment: If you just want to get an object of type `java.util.Date` then return `expiredDate.getTime());` Simple as that. No need to format here. Or, if you want a string then format it and change return type of method.

Comment: change return type of method to string ?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your replies, Yes I tried changing return type into String but my database needs a Date type to be written into it. I guess I should return my method with Date type  then change it into String in the method which writes into database?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is used to parse Dates from Strings or to format Dates to Strings. If you just want to Modify an existing date using SimpleDateFormat is the wrong approach. As Meno Hochschild already said you should just return `expiredDate.getTime()`.

Comment: Ok, how do I modify it into YYYY-MM-DD format, not full Date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … ,
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
             .plusDays( … )
)
```

## Details

Question is not clear, but it sounds like you are trying to get the current date, add some number of days (input as text) to determine an “expiration” date, and display that as text.

You are using confusing troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Getting the current date requires a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

You can use the JVM’s current default time zone. But know that the default can be changed at any moment by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM. So if crucial, ask the user for desired/expected zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

To represent a date-only value without a time-of-day and without a time zone, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Parse the number-of-days text into a `long`.

```
String input = timeFld.getText() ;
long days = Long.parseLong( input );
```

Add days to your `today` date.

```
LocalDate expiration = today.plusDays( days ) ;
```

To generate a String representing that value in standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = expiration.toString();
```

> 2017-01-23

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 or later, then you can exchange this `LocalDate` with your database via `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject` methods.

For older drivers, convert to/from the `java.sql.Date` class using new conversion methods added to the old class.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( expiration );

LocalDate expiration = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

Tip: Separate the code doing business logic (calculating the expiration) from the user-interface work of gathering input and displaying result.